# How to set Open File Dialog path explicitly?

Tags: file-opening

#### Description

I'd like to point a folder so any application will start its "File Open Dialog" in it. How can I do that?

#### Rationale

I'm naturally using many applications while working on a project, like FreeCAD, LibreCAD, VLC, SimpleScan, etc. It's frustrating to navigate to my work folder for every single one of those applications. If I could set such a path, any application will start that dialog within my work folder, so I can easily handle my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will work for *any application*. Not even inside the same graphic environment. Take for example Gnome. If you were to change that value via `dconf-editor` you'd find that for `evince` you need to set:

```
org.gnome.Evince document-directory
```

but for `gnome-screenshot` you need to set:

```
org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory
```

in `libreoffice` you'd have to set a preference:

```
Menu/Tools/Options/LIbreoffice/Paths/MyDocuments
```

and so on ...

If you always get the same Open File dialog among the applications you are interested in, you might be able to create a shortcut inside it and add it to the navigation bar.